manga where mc kills a bad guy using a gold coin
100% a b+w japanese manga. perhaps isekai?
the teenage to 20yo male mc kills a man by throwing or using telekinesis to throw a gold coin into a bad guy's head. the bad guy dies in his own office. later on, someone finds the gold coin.
